# Remove Windows 8 bootloader from another drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have deleted the partition of Windows 8 and resized the Ubuntu partition to cover the whole disk. Now I don't want Windows to show up in the boot menu.

I ran `sudo update-grub`. It shows up `Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sdb1`. I have another disk (with no OS installed) that has the the bootloader installed. How can I remove the Windows 8 bootloader from that disk?

EDIT:

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 150.0 GB, 150039945216 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 18241 cylinders, total 293046768 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd58bacbf

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda3   *        2048   293044223   146521088    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            4096   293044223   146520064   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x796e4435

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048   976769023   488383488    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: If you have not any valuable data in that disk, you can format it  with gparted. Of course you can just hide the Windows 8 from grub's entries, but if you want to remove it completely then format is the way (IMO).

Comment: @NikTh Can't I tell Ubuntu to re-install the bootloader on that disk ignoring the Windows bootloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows starting with Vista sometimes create a separate partition for **bootloader**. if that's your case you should remove that partition too and then try `sudo update-grub`. it's good if you can add your `sudo fdisk -l` output in your question.

**EDIT:**

After you added the `fdisk -l` output I should say that in your case you have no separate boot partition. you have just one partition and that's interesting (not even a swap ;)

This bring us to the next troubleshooting step: ***reinstalling the bootloader***

Boot with a live disk or live usb stick and type following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

**EDIT 2:**

After you commented that you have `swap` we should more concern about your situation! let me clarify a bit. You have two HDD and on one of them you have a EXTENDED+logical (count as one partition) for `swap` with size 150GB (wow that's too much) and on the other HDD you have a HTTP/FAT partition for your root! or your windows or maybe your data.

**Consider This Please**

It is not necessary for anyone to have such a big swap!

separate `/home` partition and `/` (named root) partition and `swap` to get a better partitioning schema.

**A good schema for personal use is:**

- a `/` partition with `EXT4` filesystem (read root partition and **Don't** confuse with `/root` that is something else) with a size between `10` to `60` GB depending on your use. I recommend more than `50`.
- a `/home` partition with `EXT4`. makes it as long as you want your personal data to be.
- (optional but recommended) a `swap` partition with size `512` MB up to double size of your RAM. sometimes you get hibernate problem if you don't have enough swap.

You can decide between between primary and logical. It doesn't matter as long as you don't want more than 4 partition. It is not going to hurt you with less than 4 partiton.

Comment: Added the output of fdisk. I don't find any extra partition for the bootloader.

Comment: @asattar please reinstall your bootloader and see what's happens

Comment: Well, I actually did reinstall the bootloader. I previously had only Windows bootloader on `/dev/sda`, so I needed to install `grub` on it.

Comment: `/dev/sda5` is swap and `/dev/sda3` is the primary partition.

Comment: Can I do `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb`?

Comment: `/dev/sda3` is labeled with EXTENDED! it can't be your your root partition. but you have 2 HDD so your root partition is on `/dev/sdb1`

Comment: Ok, I get it. I thought that Extended was something to do with the `ext` filesystem. How can I fix this?

Comment: @asattar you should install grub into `/dev/sdb1` so replace `sda5` from the first command with `sdb1`

Comment: @asattar by the way, it's not good partitioning brother. I edit my post and suggest a good one.

Comment: @asattar wait a minues. either you don't have a `/` partition! or you have installed your linux into a `FAT` partition. Did you selected `FAT` when you were installing the ubuntu?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9711/discussion-between-asattar-and-sajjadg)